# How can I create a github permalink to a line in a markdown .md or .Rmd file?

Tags: github

How can I create a permalink to specific lines in a .md or .Rmd file like README.md?

These files are rendered differently in github, so when I click on them I don't see the usual line-number editor where I can click on a line and ask it to give me the permalink to the selected lines, [as described here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-permanent-link-to-a-code-snippet/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes you *can*, link to specific lines in a Markdown file, by going to the Blame view of the file.

[image: Click the Blame button]

Then, press <kbd>y</kbd> to get a [permalink to the version of the file that you see now](https://help.github.com/articles/getting-permanent-links-to-files/). This will ensure the link persists if the file changes, is moved, renamed or deleted.

At this point, you can click a link, or Shift+click a range of lines, and the URL will update automatically.

Here is an [example link](https://github.com/google/WebFundamentals/blame/168c0a6f93dc3cce6772ccc3f78cbef92910b1e6/src/content/en/fundamentals/app-install-banners/index.md#L32-L39).

Comment: If you don't like the blame link for some reason (e.g. wanted to reference the permalink in a comment over at GitHub, so it can render the pretty preview inline), replace the word `/blame/` with `/blob/` in the URL. The disadvantage of this approach is that, navigating to the link will just open the markdown document (without autoscrolling down to the anchor).

Answer (score 2):

You can't link to a line number, because the line number anchors are provided by the GitHub code preview interface.  Since, as you mention, markdown files are rendered differently, they don't have the line number anchors that you are looking for.

You can, however, link to a header (anything starting with one or more `#`s.)  Hover over the header to make the link icon appear:

[image: GitHub header link]

Then right click the link icon and "Copy Link Address".

If you are working inside the same markdown file as your target link, you can use the [markdown anchor syntax](https://gist.github.com/asabaylus/3071099): `[link name](#anchor-name-with-hyphens)`.

Comment: This only works if you want to link to a header. If you want to link to an arbitrary line, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52266414/1269037).

Answer (score 0):

## Update:

As of 2018-10-01, since RMarkdown files are [no longer rendered to html by GitHub](https://yihui.org/en/2018/10/rmd-github/)., you can create a permalink for an RMarkdown file as you would with a typical text file.  Just view the file in GitHub, select the lines you want to create a permalink to, and then click on "..."->"Copy permalink" as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to permalink to a heading, you can press `y` on the formatted markdown document to get the commit hash in the url. Then any heading links you copy will have the permalink.

Answer (score -1):

Use a [named destination anchor](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-A). They can be used as link targets inside the same HTML document or in other documents.

Put the line

```
<a name="my-anchor"></a>
```

above the line that you want as a destination for your link.

Being empty, the `<a>` element is not displayed but it is still present in the generated HTML.

Your permalink is the URL of the document (on Github) followed by `#my-anchor`:

```
 <a href="http://github.com/user/project/blob/master/Readme.md#my-anchor">Go to line 42</a>
```

---

If your desired link destination is a header in `Readme.md`, the Markdown engine already created a named anchor for it. All you have to do is to to hover the header in the rendered page on Github and click on the link chains that appear next to the header on the left. Then you get the URL from the browser's Location bar.

*Please note that this auto-generated destination anchor is generated using the content of the header. It will change when the header content changes and you'll end up with a broken link.*

Comment: So it sounds like you can't create a permalink in the sense of linking to a line in a specific commit; instead it's a relative reference that can break if the file changes.

Comment: Put `<a name="#something"></a>` in your `Readme.md` and it won't change unless you change it. If it's hosted on Github, you **can** get a link to a specific line of any file as it was on a specific commit, and it won't change (unless the commit itself is destroyed but this is a different story and if you don't do it, it won't happen).

Comment: This only works if you can change the `.md` file. If you want to link to an arbitrary `.md` files you can't modify, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52266414/1269037).